# "Во фразе" или "в фразе" - какой из этих вариантов правильный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика

На данном сайте я наткнулся на кучу вопросов о том, как пишется та или иная фраза. Однако в некоторых случаях в вопросе используется "во фразе", а иногда "в фразе". Как должно быть на самом деле?

Comment: Почему же тогда на этом сайте столько раз употребляется "в фразе"? – Roman Podymov ========= Не хватает трёх восклицательных в вопросе. Вот у вас вводное слово не обособлено... Посмотрим, как скоро это заметят и найдут время исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлог **во** употребляется:

... перед формами слов, начинающимися сочетаниями «в, ф + согласный»

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3+%D0%B2%D0%BE

Вариант "в фразе" произносится с трудом, а на слух трудно определить наличие предлога.

Comment: Значит надо писать "во фразе"? Почему же тогда на этом сайте столько раз употребляется "в фразе"?

Comment: А что за сайт? На некоторых сайтах пишут даже "в Франции": https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attractions-g187070-Activities-France.html

Comment: Тот, на котором мы сейчас с Вами общаемся - https://rus.stackexchange.com. Введите в его поиске выражение "в фразе" и посмотрите, сколько Вам отобразится результатов.

Comment: Поиск на сайте не отсеивает результатов с раздельным местонахождением предлога и слова. Статистика по "нац. корпусу русского языка": 154 случая "во фразе" и 18 случаев "в фразе" (8,5:1). Судя по тому, что корректорами это пропускается, грубой ошибкой это не считается.

Comment: Так всё же, как нам быть? Я вот собрался ещё один вопрос задать и не могу решить, ошибка во фразе или в фразе?

Comment: Думаю, что с вариантом "во фразе" не ошибётесь. Вряд ли есть смысловое различие в употреблении разных выражений. Могу предположить, что само сочетание принадлежит преимущественно письменной речи (люди редко обсуждают вслух "фразы"), и пишущие не всегда обращают внимание на то, как это произносится или воспринимается на слух - иначе, разговорная речь отрегулировала бы написание в сторону более однозначного "во фразе", как это наблюдается с "во Франции" или "во фраке".